# Gradle - import GitHub repository and make it a subproject dependency?

Tags: java, git, gradle

I was trying to avoid multi-project builds by deploying JAR file dependencies, but it really undermined my nimble workflow and I need a faster way to make my GIT repositories dynamically add each other as dependencies. I'm sure I could write some creative deployment procedures using JAR files, but I like changes to one project to immediately ripple to other dependent projects without intermediary deployment.

I was looking through the grgit documentation, and I see that it allows branch cloning operations. But how do I extract the working tree after the clone and include it as a dependency, assuming that repo itself has its own `gradle.build` script?

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'
    compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.7'
    compile 'net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile files('path/to/my/repo') //not quite sure what to do here??? 
}

task downloadGitDependency { 
    def grgit = Grgit.clone(dir: 'path/to/my/repo', uri: 'git@github.com:ajoberstar/grgit.git')
}
build.dependsOn downloadGitDependency

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir "src/main/java"
}

jar { 
    from configurations.compile.collect { entry -> zipTree(entry) }
}
```

Comment: Two questions: a) the git clone pulls the jar files?  and b) when you say repo, is that you local gradle repo?  i.e. you can see it in .gradle/caches?  If both are true, you can probably use the compile fileTree('path/to/my/repo', include: 'jarthatyouwant.jar').  Only issue is that is messing with how gradle pull artifacts, if you poke around that folder, it has checksum and everything.  It's probably better to just clone it in a local directory.  The other concern is whether the clone will execute before it pulls down the dependency.

Comment: The GIT repository is the source code for the subproject, with its own `build.gradle` script (not JAR files). I would think the GIT clone needs to happen first and localize the working files into a subproject in the master project. Then it needs to do the build of the entire project with its subprojects.

Comment: it looks like you want to dynamically create your own settings.gradle?  Is that right?  Pull the source, have gradle create those subprojects?  You can call "include" in your buildscript.  After cloning, call include ':nameoftheproject'  I'm assuming you have code in the main project, I would bring that as a subproject and include a dependency compile ':nameoftheproject', that way gradle knows to build your cloned subprojects before build that one.  Your root project won't have any code, just build.gradle where you assemble your artifacts.

Comment: I dont know bout creating a settings.gradle dynamically. I know what projects are needed so I imagine they would be defined. But before the build is called those needed subprojects need to be copied into the master project. But let me ponder your answer and do some experimenting...

Comment: There's no way to make it working without `settings.gradle` defined. Gradle will not know how to configure project and which modules should be included.

Comment: I'm kind of thinking of an alternative way to do this. Maybe taking a multi-project approach, I could prompt the Gradle user to provide a folder path input for each needed project. The user would be prompted for the `path/to/my/repo` and that value can be stored for subsequent builds. That would probably be the most flexible approach.

Comment: Dang it, I see what you are saying. I cannot dynamically modify `settings.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

If the list of subprojects is (fairly) static and each has its own `build.gradle`, you could add them as git submodules. In your project dir, do:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:ajoberstar/grgit.git path/to/my/repo
cd path/to/my/repo
git fetch

# then either (to switch to a different branch):
git checkout -b mybranch origin/mybranch

# or (to check out a particular ref on the current branch):
git checkout deadc0de

# or both of the above (to check out a particular ref on a different branch)
```

(Note: the git URL you used in your example would add grgit as a subproject—unless this is what you want, you would use the URL of the remote repo for your subproject here. `path/tp/my/repo` is an arbitrary path within your project tree where the subproject will be cloned.)

Then, add your subproject to the main project’s build config: `import` it in `settings.gradle` and define it as a dependency in `build.gradle`.

Git will link your main modules’s commit to that particular commit of the submodule.

Be advised, however, that working with submodules in git is not without pitfalls: Don’t commit to the submodule (always commit upstream), and be sure to run `git submodule update` each time your HEAD changes (pull, merge, checkout etc.). A good article on the pitfalls of git submodules it at: https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/